# AWS S3 force download of file when preSignedRequest link clicked

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 to generate a createPresignedRequest() to a file. When the user clicks on the link it opens in a new window, I am wanting it to force download. Is there anything I can do to enable this feature. I have looked at the docs but I am not seeing what I need.

Here's my code to create the url:

```
 $s3 = new S3Client([
      'credentials'=>[
           'key'=>$key,
           'secret'=>$secret,
      ],
      'region'=>'us-west-2',
      'version'=>'2006-03-01',
 ]);
 $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
      'Bucket' => $buckname,
      'Key'    => $file,
 ]);
 $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+7 days');
 $secureUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
 echo $secureUrl; // When the user clicks on the link - how can I force download the file instead of open in a new window.
```

Comment: Related: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force a download when generating the pre-signed URL, by adding [`ResponseContentDisposition`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobject) to the `GetObject` parameters.

```
'ResponseContentDisposition' => '<string>',
```

This directs S3 to set a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header with the value of `<string>` when the signed URL is used.  The object remains unchanged.

The value to use for `'<string>'` can be one of these:

```
'attachment'
'attachment; filename="some-filename.jpg"'
```

The second example will cause most browsers to save the file with the name you specified, instead of its name in S3.  There is a single space after the `;` after the word `attachment`.

When you do this, you'll notice that the signed URL now contains `&response-content-dispositon=...` which is mentioned in the [S3 API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).

Alternately, you can set the `Content-Disposition` to the desired value when you upload the object to S3 and this will automatically be present on all downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on content-type set. If suppose content-type is jpeg or txt which browser can show; then it is shown in the browser.. If browser is not capable of viewing the content-type then it automatically downloads it for example exe file.